# Expand & refill data.frame by values within group

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to replace the NA values after explanding a dataframe, by group. My data represent average daily values for period of different length, and I would like to fill this avergae value for longer period. Great example how to fll in the first value is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74478922/fill-na-values-per-group-based-on-first-value-of-a-group)  but I can't figure out how to adapt it for my data, as I have more groups (one group per day).

Example:

```
  day daily_count
1   4          10
2   6          20
3  10          30
```

I want to fill in average daily values for ever day in period 2:12 days:

Expected outcome:

```
   day daily_count
1    2          10  # filled in daily count for all DOY preceeding 4
2    3          10
3    4          10
4    5          20  # filled in daily count for all DOY preceeding 6, etc.
5    6          20
6    7          30
7    8          30
8    9          30
9   10          30
10  11          NA   # NA as I do not have data anymore
11  12          NA
```

What i get instead (incorrectly filled NA values):

```
   day daily_count
1    2          NA
2    3          NA
3    4          10
4    5          NA
5    6          20
6    7          NA
7    8          NA
8    9          NA
9   10          30
10  11          NA
11  12          NA
```

Here is my example, trying to consider the 'daily counts' as group:

```
day.range = 2:12
df <- data.frame(day= c(4, 6, 10),
                 daily_count = c(10, 20, 30))

# expand table - different grouping approaching, but no one works properly
df %>% 
  right_join(data.frame(day= day.range))  %>% 
  arrange(day) %>% #%>% 
  mutate(day_grp =  replace_na(daily_count, first(daily_count))) #%>%  #replace_na(val, first(val))) %>% 
group_by(day_grp) %>%  
mutate(daily_count = replace_na(daily_count, first(daily_count))) #%>%
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `tidyr::complete` and `tidyr::fill` you could do:

```r
library(tidyr)

df |>
  complete(day = day.range) |>
  fill(daily_count, .direction = "up")
#> # A tibble: 11 × 2
#>      day daily_count
#>    <dbl>       <dbl>
#>  1     2          10
#>  2     3          10
#>  3     4          10
#>  4     5          20
#>  5     6          20
#>  6     7          30
#>  7     8          30
#>  8     9          30
#>  9    10          30
#> 10    11          NA
#> 11    12          NA
```

Comment: Thank you @Stefan, I have learnt some new things! please, what is benefit of using `|>` instead of `%>%` pipe? They seem doing the same thing?

Comment: Personally I switched to `|>` as I do not have to load any packages to use it. But using `|>` has actually some downsides, i.e. there are some operations which work with `%>%` but not with `|>`.